# One line custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

In a Proc I would like to validate that the provided statement returns true.

I tried the following:

```
validate :home, Proc.new { |c| c.home.kitchen.present? }
```

It does not work. It does not show validations errors when no kitchen is present.

Do I have to write it like this:

```
validate :home_kitchen_must_be_present

def home_kitchen_must_be_present
   ....
```

**Or is there an available syntax to write it in one line?** Thanks

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: First, you need to add error to the object to invalidate it. Second, what are `home` and 'kitchen` here? Validations are for attributes (columns in db). Are these two different attributes of your model? Maybe you can show us your schema and explain more what you want to achieve here.

Comment: I recommend posting your model associations and/or schema. It looks like you are trying to verify that a nested object is present when adding/updating a primary object which would probably require a custom validation method. If kitchen is column inside table Home, then it is a whole different can of worms. We just need to know what you are working with.

Comment: Then again if kitchen and home are columns in a Building table, you would be able to do a conditional validation.

Answer (score 0):

**Using proc**

> validates :home,presence: true, if: Proc.new { |c| c.home.kitchen.present? }

**using a method:**

```
validates :home, presence: true, if: :home_kitchen_must_be_present

def home_kitchen_must_be_present
  true # do your checking and return true or false
end
```

Comment: `validates` is for Rails validators (and custom validator classes ending with Validator if that’s what you're into), and `validate` is for your custom validator methods.

Comment: @Зелёный  I know difference between validate and validates.   Now what's problem with my code when it can achieve what he wants?

Comment: `validates :home, if: ...` doesn't works and raise an error, because it need at least one validator, like `presence` or `length` or whatever. `validates :home, presence: true, if: ...` this works. Check your code. Read the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: what you created is a conditional rails validation. The problem is it is based on an association that won't be present if the object doesn't exist. i.e. home.kitchen.present? the overall problem is we don't know what exactly he is tying to accomplish given the little information provided in the question.

Comment: btw... I like lambda' for these conditionals but that's just me. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯